# GWT: Returning multiple styles for the same CSS field

Tags: css, gwt, styles, cssresource

In a CssResource, Can I return multiple style class names from the same method?

[please forgive any mistakes in code - I'm trying to recreate at home, from memory].
I have the following library code (which I can't change):

```
void render(ClientBundle1 bundle) {
    setInnerHtml("<div class=\" + bundle.css().style() + \"/>");
}
```

The bundle is straight forward:

```
interface ClientBundle1 extends ClientBundle {
    @Source("css1.css")
    CssResource1 css();
}
```

and the css resource:

```
interface CssResource1 extends CssResource {
    style1();
}
```

and the css1.css:

```
.style1 {width=10; height=20}
```

Now - I'd like to _*partially*_ override "style1" with another style (only override the height, not the width) of from my own css (css2.css). However, my css2.css is declared like this:

```
.style2 {height=30}
```

So I'd like to partially override css1.style1 with css2.style2 (different class name).

If this was vanilla HTML, I would've just written:

...import css1 then css2...

```
  <div class="style1 style2"/>
```

However, since this is GWT, I would need something like this:

```
interface ClientBundle2 extends ClientBundle1 {
    @Source("css1.css", "css2.css")
    CssResource2 css();
}
```

and the css resource:

```
interface CssResource2 extends CssResource1 {
    @Classname("style1", "style2")
    style();
}
```

but of course, the above isn't possible in GWT.

Is there a way of assigning two style class names per a single style method?

Answer (score 2):

Several options, none of which are exactly what you are asking for:

#### Add more than one class:

Where ever you are applying that style, just as you would say `<div class="style1 style2"/>`, add both styles. If in UiBinder, do something like `<g:Widget addStyleNames="{css.style1} {css.style2}" />`, and if in Java, just add both classes:

```
widget.addStyleNames(css.style1() + " " + css.style2());
```

or

```
widget.addStyleNames(css.style1());
widget.addStyleNames(css.style2());
```

#### Override just that style:

Why not have more than one style rule for either `style1` or `style2`? Several ways, depending on what you are after:

css1.css:

```
.style1 {width:10px; height:20px}
```

and css2.css:

```
.style1 {height:30px}
```

Used in this CssResource/ClientBundle:

```
interface CssResource2 extends CssResource1 {
    String style();
}
interface MyClientBundle extends ClientBundle {
    @Source({"css1.css", "css2.css}) 
    CssResource2 css();
}
```

Will result in this being (more or less) the style:

```
.style1 {width:10px; height:30px}
```

Since later CSS rules with equal weight override earlier ones.

Alternatively, something like:

css1.css:

```
.style1, .style2 {width:10px; height:20px}
```

css2.css:

```
.style2 {height:30px}
```

Will result in anything with `style1` being 10x20, while anything with `style2` would be 10x30. The `@ClassName` annotation can be used to make `CssResource2` more or less ignore the earlier defined style.

Comment: Thanks, but, as you've said, it doesn't help. The first solution is a no go because it's library code, not my code that generates the HTML. The second solution is a no go because the whole idea is to have css2 with all of my customizations matching different parts in the library. Since each part of the library use "generic" names (like "trigger" or "button") it's problematic for me to override one part without overriding the other.

Comment: I'm not sure you are seeing how CssResource/ClientBundle works then - this isn't what you asked for, but it should work, as when you create a new `CssResource` type with its own `@Source`, it will get new obfuscated names, which won't conflict with those generated from other CssResources (i.e. `CssResource1.trigger` might be 'GXHT' while `CssResource2.trigger` might be 'GXRT')

Comment: Yes, but is still need a CSS with the style name dictated by the library. Which means I need multiple CSS files to override different parts of the library because they chose to reuse style names from different CSS files.

Comment: great to find that "addStyleNames" can be used in a UiBinder widget! thanks.